# Enterprise Developer account or Standard Developer account?

Tags: iphone, ipad

We're developing an iPad application for a client, who wishes to distribute the application to only those customers who have purchased the license from him for 'x' number of users. For example, if an university buys the license from him for say 50 users/devices or another company may buy the license from him for 100 users/devices. What would be the best way to distribute such an app. After doing some research iv come across 2 ways for this but each with its own hiccups.

1) Distribute it through the App Store with a standard developer license and authenticate the users of the app. Only if the users are authenticated by the server, would they be able to access and use the application. This allows my client to restrict the users to only those who have obtained licenses form him.

But i have heard that Apple would reject such apps that provide only exclusive access to some users and not to all.

2) The other option is the Enterprise Developer account where he would host the apps on his site and the clients who have obtained licenses only can download it. However, I believe that enterprise applications can only be developed for in-house employees. i.e if he has the enterprise account, the app can only be used for his employees as it would work only for the devices authenticated with the unique DUNS number.

Anyone has any workarounds for this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can multiple clients of my client have enterprise accounts and run the same app? i.e does Apple have any restrictions that one app developed under the enterprise license of one company, can only run in that company and the same app cannot run in another company as that would be a violation of the "in-house" use?

Comment: Hi @Nathan, we just had our app approved for the store so no problem with authenticating to external services. It took exactly seven days. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

The client I have just developed an app for has the requirement for users to login to their service before they can use the app. They place the app in the store with a clear indication a login is required. The app is free to download so no one gets caught paying for something they can't use.

We have just submitted the latest app to the store and are waiting for approval<sup>*</sup>. When submitting we included a full login for the reviewers to test the app with. This was in the review notes and remains confidential. They have an existing app already approved which works the same way.

As part of the app we also included a demo mode with static content bundled with the app which allowed access to all the functionality but only for that very limited set of data.

The client has the Enterprise programme which allowed us to beta test the app with designated users but that was with the usual 100 device limit (with devices able to be removed at renewal time only). Both the individual developer and the company program are allowed the same number of devices but you want to be able to join the clients team as developer so they should go for the Company program. The client will need to be the Agent for the submission and that is fixed as the first account they sign up with. We're trying to change the agent for our company now and it's not something you can do online you have to send Apple a request. They should then add you as a developer for their program. You can be a member or an admin but only they, as the Agent, will get to sign the app for distribution.

I sure hope you aren't correct about rejection because of the login service or I'm going to have a very disappointed client on my hands.

**<sup>*</sup>EDIT:** Our application was approved by Apple at the first attempt so there was no problem with this approach.

Comment: Yeah im not really sure of the rejection part. It was just someone's opinion but i wasnt sure. I do hope that Apple doesnt reject such scenarios. Do let me know once your app is approved.

Comment: Resurrecting an old thread, but we've had an app rejected due to requiring users to log on.

Comment: @Carl did they point out which part of the guidelines they rejected you for? We made an update to this app several months ago which was still approved but that's not to say next time it won't be rejected. From other rejections they usually list the reasons.

Comment: Been a while now! We developed the app but it was published by the client, and all we were told was that it was rejected and that taking away the login screen would fix it.